# Prevent user to click if any of the buttons was clicked

Tags: android, button, click

I have a lot of buttons on every activity of my app, clicking a button will lead to open new activity. My problem is while the activity has not showed up yet, and the user click again on the same button or other button, the there will be another activity to be showed up.

How do I prevent this? Is there any quick and clean way like setting option in the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to give a more general and reliable solution here. Although the answer Bhavik Parmar suggested is quite close but uses `ProgressDialog`, which is already deprecated. You can also use this approach to show loading while data is being downloading from your server or some API is hit and you are waiting for it's response.

Firstly, you will have to create a class for example `BaseActivity` which extends `AppCompatActivity` and second a layout for `ProgressBar`.

**Below is the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black_10"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_progress_bar"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Now in the BaseActivity you need to add code below**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View progressBarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (progressBarView == null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
            progressBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_progress_bar, null);
            parent.addView(progressBarView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(isLoading()) {
            hideLoading();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(isLoading()) {
            hideLoading();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void showLoading() {
        if(this.isFinishing()) {
           return;
        }

        if (progressBarView != null) {
            progressBarView.bringToFront();
            progressBarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void hideLoading() {
        if(!this.isFinishing()) {
            if(progressBarView != null) {
                progressBarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isLoading() {
        return (progressBarView != null && progressBarView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**Now wherever you need to implement this functionality, extend this `BaseActivity`, for example if you need it in your `HomeActivity` then make the `HomeActivity` extend `BaseActivity` .**

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {...}
```

**Now all you have to do is call this `showLoading` function in your `onClick()` of the button**

```
showLoading();
```

And you will get a clean loading effect and all the other buttons will not be able to be clicked. The other benefit of this approach is that the user gets to know that something is loading now and he/she has to wait and clicking anywhere won't do much right now.

Now you might ask that when will this loading be closed, so in the code of `BaseActivity` you can see that `onResume()` and `onStop()` check loading and hide it according to android life cycle. So that will be handled automatically. Although you can change the implementation the way you like.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain flag variable for that For example

```
 onClick(){
    if(flag){
      flag = false;

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 flag = true;
            }
        },800);

     //Code To open second activity 
    }

    }
```

This will prevent opening multiple activities

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but when do I reset the flag? at the end of the code of the First Activity , the Second Activity still not show up.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `ProgressDialog` for that. That will improve your UI and it will also solve your problem.

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
    progress.setMessage("Loading ...Please Wait! ");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
```

When you want to show progress dialog you can call it like this

```
progress.show();
```

And when you do not want to display it you can simply remove it by calling `cancel` method like this

```
progress.cancel();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but how do I stop the dialog when the second activity has fully loaded?

Comment: You can declare `ProgressDialog` globally for that. Tick my answer if it is appropriate.

Comment: You could place progress.cancel() on onPause() method